# i keep getting this errno 4058 with ENOENT when i use "npm install"

Tags: json, github, npm, errno, enoent

whenever i use "npm install", it says the following

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-14T19_25_44_768Z-debug-0.log

ive tried looking everywhere else on this site and i cant seem to get rid of it. here is the package.json for anyone that needs it...

```
{
   "name": "project-x",
   "version": "1.5.9",
   "main": "src/index.js",
   "license": "Unlicensed",
   "scripts": {
      "start": "node ."
   },
   "engines": {
      "node": "14.x"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "@discordjs/uws": "^10.149.0",
      "@skyra/timestamp": "^1.0.0",
      "chalk": "4.1.2",
      "discord.js": "localip/discord.js#master",
      "discord.js-light": "localip/discord.js-light#master",
      "dotenv": "github:andreialecu/dotenv#feat-multiline",
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "json5": "^2.2.0",
      "moment": "^2.29.1",
      "phin": "github:localip/phin"
   }
}
```

and if you also need the package-lock.json, lmk

i tried clearing the npm cache, updating npm, reinstalling, making a new cache, deleting package-lock. none of it fixed the problem. could it be something to do with the github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
```

Make sure git is installed and added to your path before running this command again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today and solved it with this installation.

```
npm install -g npm
```

Here is the link:

https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm